# Photoshop scripting - Magic Eraser Tool

Tags: photoshop

I'm trying to make a photoshop (.jsx) script that doeas the following.

```
Open files from folder
For each file in folder
Take Magic Eraser Tool
Click on the edge of the document (document width -1, document height -1)
Save for web as PNG
```

I am able to do everything except click on the edge of the document to erase the background.. How do I do that?
I am now able to open an image and select the Magic Eraser Tool but I can't manipulate the mouse click on the edge so it would go transparent.
All images have a white frame so it's ok for me to click on the edge.

Any suggestions?

Thank you for your time!

// EDIT:
How do I set the tolerance on the selected tool?

Andrej

Comment: Can you please add the code that you have thus far?

Answer (score 0):

There are limitations to scripting tools in PS. In scripting if you set the magic eraser to imagewidth-1, imageheight -1 you'll get an error.

```
// =======================================================
var id16821 = charIDToTypeID( "Fl  " );
var desc3348 = new ActionDescriptor();
var id16822 = charIDToTypeID( "From" );
var desc3349 = new ActionDescriptor();
var id16823 = charIDToTypeID( "Hrzn" );
var id16824 = charIDToTypeID( "#Pxl" );
desc3349.putUnitDouble( id16823, id16824, 0.0 ); //x
var id16825 = charIDToTypeID( "Vrtc" );
var id16826 = charIDToTypeID( "#Pxl" );
desc3349.putUnitDouble( id16825, id16826, 0.0 ); //y
var id16827 = charIDToTypeID( "Pnt " );
desc3348.putObject( id16822, id16827, desc3349 );
var id16828 = charIDToTypeID( "Tlrn" );
desc3348.putInteger( id16828, 32 ); //tolerance
var id16829 = charIDToTypeID( "AntA" ); //Antialias
desc3348.putBoolean( id16829, true );
var id16830 = charIDToTypeID( "Usng" );
var id16831 = charIDToTypeID( "FlCn" );
var id16832 = charIDToTypeID( "BckC" );
desc3348.putEnumerated( id16830, id16831, id16832 );
var id16833 = charIDToTypeID( "Md  " );
var id16834 = charIDToTypeID( "BlnM" );
var id16835 = charIDToTypeID( "Clar" );
desc3348.putEnumerated( id16833, id16834, id16835 );
//var id16872 = charIDToTypeID( "Cntg" );
//desc3355.putBoolean( id16872, false ); Contiguous set to false
executeAction( id16821, desc3348, DialogModes.NO );
```

Are you just trying to remove the background layer?